# SSIS to import tables from Access DB to SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ms-access

im trying to design an SSIS package to import 80 tables from Access DB into SQL DB, I have done it through the export and import wizard then saved the SSIS package but i didnt like the way the package was designed as it had 80 different source and destination connections.

Is there a way to Loop through the Access Tables? create each one in SQL DB and import the data into SQL?

Thanks

Comment: The tables that you are importing from Access is the schema the same for all 80 tables?

Comment: Yes They are all the same, but i want to import them into a new schema.

Comment: Are all the tables from Access going to the same table in SQL server?  What type of source connection has the wizard created for the Access tables?

Comment: The Wizard created 80 OLEDB source connection reading from access and 80 OLEDB destination connection related to SQL.
Each table is supposed to be created on the sql server having the same name but different schema name.